# Firebase storage security rules not working for folder

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have  the following rule in my Firebase Storage. But still, I am able to access the images when I have the link that starts with "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/", even when I am not authorized/authenticated. I have a folder called **toyCarImages** and I want to allow writes from the public and reads from only authorized accounts

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this issue? I am using `getDownloadUrl()` method in my application. How secure is it when using `getDownloadUrl()`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A download URL gives public read-only access to the file to anyone who has that URL. Access to a file through a download URL is not secured by the rules of your storage bucket.

If you want to block a certain download URL, your only option is to revoke that URL from the Firebase console.

Comment: Is there any way to show the image on <img src=""> without using download URL?

Comment: Well, you could download the data through the SDK, and generate a `base64` image out of it. https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+base64+data+url+from+image+data